# MongoDB Update nested Array object where there is a match in array document

Tags: c#, mongodb

Here is my MongoDB Document

```
{  
   "_id":20,
   "GroupId":"45",
   "Name":"Some Name",
   "NestedArray":[  
      {  
         "Id":3,
         "Name":"NesName",
         "IsDeleted":false
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to write a update statement like (in SQL interpretation)

```
update MyCollections.NestedArray set MyCollections.NestedArray[x].IsDeleted = true where MyCollections.NestedArray[x].Id = 3
```

Here is what I tried

```
 var groupFilter = Builders<MyType>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, 45);
 var nestedArayDocUpdate = Builders<MyType>.Update.Set(x => x.NestedArray[0].IsDeleted, true);
 mongoDbRepository.UpdateMany(groupFilter, nestedArayDocUpdate,
               new UpdateOptions {IsUpsert = false, BypassDocumentValidation = false});
```

using `MongoDB 3.2` how can I come up with a MongoDB C# driver query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it.

```
 var updateBuilder = Builders<Type>.Update.
                           .Set(x => x.NestedArray[-1].IsActive, false)
                           .Set(x => x.NestedArray[-1].IsDeleted, true);

mongoDbRepository.UpdateOne( Builders<Type>.Filter.Where( 
   x => x.NestedArray.Any(c => c.Id == categoryId)), updateBuilder);
```